# Change defaule user log in, in beaglebone running Debian

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

When the Beaglebone black boot it log in username:Debian by default I want to change it to log in root by default how can I do that,I am running Debian

Answer (score 2):

Open the configuration file for the desktop environment.

For e.g. if you are using lightdm use `/usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config` to view the configuration.

**Enable autologin**

Look up these lines in lightdm configuration file, uncomment them and customize to your preference.

```
[SeatDefaults]
#autologin-user=
#autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look online at the Debian resources section for surviving the command line in Linux, you will see a small couple of sections on it. Here is the site you can visit to cure this hangover.

See: https://wiki.debian.org/ShellCommands?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=connman&titlesearch=Titles

That Wiki has information on how to survive the command prompt for Linux and Debian.

Seth

P.S. Look under "U" on the Wiki page. They have a change user information section. Oh and look to passwd for changing your password.